odoo 8 how to make a filter to search product in sale_order_line
I want to make a filter to search product to sale_order_line but got error.
<field name="line_ids.product_id" string="Sales" filter_domain="[('line_ids.product_id','ilike',self)]"/>

What is the correct one?

What is the error? Where do you want to search, on the order list?

You have to make the filter like this:
<field name="line_ids" string="Products" filter_domain="[('line_ids.product_id.name', 'ilike', self)]"/>


Like what Sir ?

He forgot to indent the code

They already defined a related product field used in the sale order search view, which lets you view results in place
